# Migrate from Hibernate API to JPA api in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I used in my application Hibernte API, include SessionFactory etc, but I want go to JPA Api and using EntityManager etc. When I using Hibernate API all works fine, but when i try using JPA Api i have problems. The steps I've done:

In my Apache server i added to context.xml:

```
   <Resource name="jdbc/iBank" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
         username="HR" password="asdfghj"
         maxActive="20" maxIdle="3" maxWait="10000"
         poolPreparedStatements="true"
         maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
         validationQuery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" />
```

Added file persistence.xml in src\main\resources\META-INF

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="iBankPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/iBank</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Modify root-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="HR" />
        <property name="password" value="asdfghj" />
    </bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="iBankPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.piotr.ibank.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                true
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="pl.piotr.ibank.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

</beans>
```

in web.xml I added:

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/iBank</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

In application I have login using Spring Security, but after above changes I can't login. On the server  I don't have any errors. What mistakes I made in the configuration?

Comment: Why do you try to use JTA when you actually aren't using that? You don't need to declare your datasource in the persistence.xml remove it (as well as the configuration and the resource-ref in your web.xml. Transaction type should be RESOURCE_LOCAL not JTA.

Comment: @M. Deinum Ok, all works. I change to RESOURCE_LOCAL, delete datasource in persistence.xml and delete resource-ref in web.xml. I too delete the resource in context.xml in Apache Tomcat server, and all work. I don't need this too?

Comment: No as it is pretty useless as you ae defining the datasource in your spring configuration. The one in JNDI only takes up resources. If you want to use that simply use a JNDI lookup in spring to get the datasource.